# How to fix All "com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version "

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies, androidx

I am creating an app. But the Gradle file goes error.
Please help me make the versions of dependencies same

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'


}
```

Comment: move to androidx

Comment: not fixed by trying both above mentioned methods

Comment: Migrate your project in Androidx and use latest libray https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your libraries coming from **com.android.support** package are having  same verison as of your **compileSdkVersion**